# Sending ethernet frames from kernel module

Tags: frame, kernel-module, ethernet, network-interface

I have a kernel module that would like to send pre-fabricated ethernet frames from user space such as custom ARP, and other protocols (I'm trying to bypass tcp/ip stack on linux and create custom one for my needs). Frames are valid and complete with all necessary things. The only part that remains is to send them somehow to the queue on eth0 interface. What is the best solution to do this?

For snatching incoming packets I am using netfilter API with the earliest hook possible. I can not use raw sockets from user space due to the need of sudo and also due to my custom requirements.

Edit: I was able to achieve my goals with `dev_queue_xmit()`. However, I am still wondering if there is another solution that accesses the driver directly.

```
static void SendFrame(void)
{
    struct sk_buff* skb = dev_alloc_skb(1518);
    skb->dev = __dev_get_by_name(&init_net, "eth0");
    skb_reserve(skb, NET_IP_ALIGN);
    skb->data = skb_put(skb, ethFrameBytes);
    memcpy(skb->data, pEthFrame, ethFrameBytes);

    if (dev_queue_xmit(skb) != NET_XMIT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR, KERN_ERR "Error: unable to send the frame\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can actually send raw L2 frames from user space without tinkering with the kernel: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html

Comment: Not sure what your custom requirements are. As for sudo, it is enough to have the CAP_NET_RAW capability which you can grant to your program via setcap. No need to be full root necessarily.

Comment: Sadly both RAW and packet() are out of options. I would like to access the driver / frame queue of eth0 directly. It seems everything on Linux is done with usage of skb, which can be forwarded into their own queue. I should probably stick with them since my knowledge of embedded Linux is elementary.